# How to travel the rows of sql table using index in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I have two DB and I want to transfer data from DB A tables to DB B tables. All tables from both DB have same syntax. I have this method that takes an argument name of the table. First for loop will travel the columns and I need another for or something else that travels the rows of that specific column. That switch-case retrieve the specific datatype from table column and store it into a field and after I use that field to insert the value in the same place in the DB B. Please some suggestion? I let my trash code below:

```
public void getAndInsertData(String nameOfTable) {

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB1, user1, password1);
        Statement s1 = con1.createStatement();

        Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB2, user2, password2);
        Statement s2 = con2.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs1 = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + nameOfTable);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd1 = rs1.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd1.getColumnCount();

        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {

            String columnName = rsmd1.getColumnName(column);
            int columnType = rsmd1.getColumnType(column);

            // for (int row = 1; row <= nrRows; row++) {

            switch (columnType) {

            case 4:
                int integerValue = rs1.getInt(row);
                String integerQuery = "insert into " + nameOfTable + " (" + columnName + ") VALUES(" + integerValue
                        + ");";
                s2.executeUpdate(integerQuery);
                s2.close();

                break;
            case 12:
                String varcharValue = rs1.getString(row);
                String varcharQuery = "insert into " + nameOfTable + " (" + columnName + ") VALUES(" + varcharValue
                        + ");";
                s2.executeUpdate(varcharQuery);
                s2.close();

            default:
                System.out.println("Default");
                break;

            }
        }

        // }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Transfer done...");
    }

}
```

Comment: it feels to me that u r probably better off with sql dump.

Comment: You need to insert the entire row, not insert a row per (column X row). And if you are going to do things with `columnType`, then for readability, I recommend to use the `java.Types` constants instead of using magic numbers.

Comment: I understand, can you give me please a code example for how to insert the entire row there, please...